# nuget package being removed on build

Tags: visual-studio, wix, nuget, visual-studio-2017

I have a Wix Toolset boostrapper UI project which I'd like to "host" certain assemblies which the UI project itself does not need (I'm trying to simplify my life by having Wix only look in the setup UI's bin directory for all the assemblies).

I can add, say, AutoFac to the UI project. But when I build the project, the Autofac dependency gets stripped out and its DLL is not copied to the bin directory. This isn't terribly surprising since Autofac is not used in the UI project itself, so I guess it's some kind of optimization.

What I'd like to do is override that optimization in this case, and force VS to add the Autofac assemblies to the bin directory.

Is there a VS setting to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a VS setting to do this?

If I understand you correctly, you want to force VS to add the Autofac assemblies to bin directory, you can try to **add a copy task in the post build event to copy the Autofac assemblies to the bin directory after build** (Right click project->Properties->Build Event->Post-build event command line).

```
xcopy.exe $(AutofacPath)Autofac.dll $(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)
```

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

**Update for Mark comment:**

> But a post-build copy requires that nuget "installed" the Autofac package, which is what it's not doing.

Yes, you could copy from some other project where Autofac is. What`s more, the build event can do more things. You can use another command line to install the Autofac in the post-build event before xcopy commandline:

```
D:\nuget.exe install AutoFac
```

With this command, nuget will download that package, and set it into the Bin folder.

[image]

Now things will be simple, we just need to add below command line in the post-build event:

```
D:\nuget.exe install AutoFac
xcopy.exe "$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)Autofac.4.6.0\lib\net45\Autofac.dll" "$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)"
```

**Note:** You need to specify the path where nuget.exe is located in the command line, like `D:\`.

Comment: Reasonable suggestion, @Leo-MSFT. But a post-build copy requires that nuget "installed" the Autofac package, which is what it's not doing. I could do a post build copy from some other project where Autofac is, in fact, used, but that feels pretty kludgy.

Comment: @MarkOlbert, thanks for you reply. According to your comment, I have update my answer, hope you can get more useful info. If above answer resolve your question, you can mark it as answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues. If not, please let me know your question for free, I will keep follow it.

Comment: It doesn't quite answer my question, Leo, because what I want to do is to keep VS from deleting the nuget package reference. But it's a workaround, so I've upvoted it.